# Qt strange behavior

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, gdb, qt5

it may be duplicated my previous question but I really discouraged.
I am porting now my Windows Qt application to Linux Ubuntu. It compiled without problems. But it's occurs something strange while debugging or running

[image: screenshot]

this is screenshot I maked while debugging.
Shortly, I have 2 singletons - CoreManager and Config. Hire i am trying to get one of them - CoreManager. But debugger shows it as instance of Config!! It just impossible!

Here part of CoreManager code:

```
CoreManager * ptr = NULL;

CoreManager *CoreManager::instance()
{
    if(ptr == NULL) ptr = new CoreManager();
    return ptr;
}
```

At Windows it worked without problems.
Both singletons classes are in dll btw.

- Ubuntu 13.10 x64
- Qt 5.2.0 64 bits (also tried 5.2.1 5.2.2 from git)
- gcc 4.8
- gdb 7.6.1

Comment: Have you checked the value and type of ptr in the debugger before and after the CoreManager::instance() call?

Comment: It is strange but ptr points to Config instance. Just impossible! ptr initialized at first instance() call and before it must be NULL. I placed breakpoint inside instance() function and at first call ptr was already initialized with Config ... How can it be?!! I checked it now in Windows and it's going as expected - firstly ptr is NULL and after instance() was called it initialized with CoreManager instance

Comment: It is possible that another unrelated part of the code has a bug and writes into the wrong place in memory after CoreManager was initialized to NULL (by the way, please consider using something more modern like nullptr) but way before the instance is created. I didn't use qtcreator for a while, so can you put a breakpoint that activates only on data change?

Comment: @folibis Put a breakpoint at the point where you define ptr = NULL and then step through your code.

Comment: CoreManager is singleton and cannot be inialized but only with instance(). so I put a breakpoint at firsl line of instance() and when it reached this line ptr already initialized!! But it imposible, there is no part of code that can reach ptr ...

Comment: Are the members correctly shown? Might be some gdb or QtCreator bug, but if the members are correct, it shouldn't prevent one from debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It really seems like Qt Creator bug (or less likely gdb bug).

From menu bar in Qt Creator, you can open Window/Views/"Debugger Log" and enter `print cm` command to "Command" field to see what gdb tells you about `cm` symbol.

Comment: Yes it looks like bug, just because it is impossible what I see in debugger )) now I paid attention that cm and config variables have same address so may be some memory offset here is wrong or something else.